# Ruby on Rails and Nokogiri: How to update attribute in database using a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rss, nokogiri

I am working on a rails app where I get an rss feed from BBC for news stories. I then store the news story's title, summary, and url from the rss feed. There is a blank column for images in my db at first, because I visit the url for the story and use nokogiri to scrape the main image's url afterwards through a rake task. Once I have the url for the image I try saving the item, with the newly updated attribute, to my database. However, whenever I run my rake task it doesn't work and I get errors. Here's the code:

```
task :getimg => :environment do

stories = FeedEntry.all

    stories.each do |story|

        url = story.url

        doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

        if doc.at_css(".full-width img")
            img = doc.at_css(".full-width img")[:src]
            story.image = img #my attempt to update the story's attribute
            story.save! #does this save work?
        elsif doc.at_css(".body-width img")
            img = doc.at_css(".body-width img")[:src]
            story.image = img # my attempt to update the story's attribute
            story.save! #does this save work?
        end


    end
end
```

FeedEntry is my model for the news stories and here's the output in the console:

```
rake getimg --trace
** Invoke getimg (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute getimg
rake aborted!
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-africa-29184590#sa-ns_mchannel=rss&ns_source=PublicRSS20-sa
/Users/abhasarya/rails_projects/news_reader/lib/tasks/image_scraper.rake:9:in `initialize'
```

I know I am doing something wrong, and I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone can point me to the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to require 'open-uri' in your rake task

```
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
```